# how to round trip a bash associative array to a text file?

Tags: bash

I want to memorize an associative array between different script runs. What I have so far is that given a text file containing one key/value pair:

```
(
[james]=bond
)
```

Is a script to load that into an associative array, add to it, then echo it out in a way which can be redirected into a second file:

```
#!/bin/bash
file=`cat $1`
key=$2
value=$3
declare -A row="$file"
row[$key]=$value
echo "("
for server in "${!row[@]}"
    do echo "[$server]=${row[$server]}"; done
echo ")"
```

then I can run it as:

```
./arrays.sh file1 honey rider > file2 ; mv file2 file1
```

Giving

```
(
[james]=bond
[honey]=rider
)
```

Yet it seems very clunky. Is there a cleaner way to do this?

Comment: `declare -p hash > file` to save the `hash` associative array. `source file` to restore.

Comment: It should probably be `arrays.bash`...

Answer (score 14, accepted):

In `bash`, `declare -p` can be used to dump the definition of a variable as shell code ready to be interpreted, so you can do updates to the file with:

```
#! /bin/bash -
file=${1?}; shift
declare -A row
source -- "$file" || exit
while [ "$#" -ge 2 ]; do
  row[$1]=$2
  shift 2
done
declare -p row > "$file"
```

Note that it's important that the file be generated and sourced in the same locale (at least same `LC_CTYPE` category).

A script to show the contents of the file would be:

```
#! /bin/bash -
file=${1?}; shift
declare -A row
source -- "$file"
for i in "${!row[@]}"
do
  printf 'key  : %s\n' "$i"
  printf 'value: %s\n' "${row[$i]}"
done
```

Comment: Hooray for self-qualifying parameters! But would a more specific error string not be more useful?

Comment: @mikeserv, sure, but that's beyond the point of the answer. By all means, please do add proper syntax checking as appropriate. One may also want to check that there be an even number of arguments after the file name (or use the odd single argument as a means to remove a single element).

Comment: I dunno... Maybe don't ask me to edit... You're not supposed to invite the vampires in... But what's done is done, I guess.

Comment: oh, sorry. I guess I shouldn't have taken that literally? I did do as you asked though and made it a little more robust without complicating it.

Comment: Would `mapfile` not be a safer alternative to `source` to read in the contents of the file?

Comment: @ec2011, with recent versions of `bash` (more recent than was available at the time that answer was written) you would be able to use `readarray -td '' array` to read NUL-delimited records into a *regular* array and then convert it to an associative array.